# Can't use "int" or "Integer"?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I turn strings into integers in Android?  I have tried looking up examples but I can't use `int`, `parseInt`, `Integer`, `toNumber` or `new` for example (they do not populate as options of code to use, and they turn red if I try to keep going). I have no idea why, or what I'm doing wrong. I've even uninstalled/reinstalled Android Studio (went from Canary to Release Candidate).

I have two textViews that populate with random integers (result & resultHist1), and I want the third textView (calcHist1) to sum them if resultHist1 isn't blank.  It appears my best option is something like the below, but I can't seem to make it work.  Any ideas?

```
        val a = result.toString().toInt()
        val b = resultHist1.toString().toInt()

        if (resultHist1.text.isNotBlank()) {
            calcHist1.text = (a+b).toString()
        } else {
            calcHist1.text = ""
```

Currently, as soon as resultHist1 would populate, the app crashes in my AVD and I see no exception thrown in my Event Log.

If more detail is needed please let me know.  I am determined to figure this out!

---

Logcat Update:

```
2020-05-15 23:27:00.713 17953-17953/? I/mple.simpledic: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-05-15 23:27:00.721 17953-17953/? I/mple.simpledic: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-05-15 23:27:00.722 17953-17953/? W/mple.simpledic: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-05-15 23:27:00.766 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice I/mple.simpledic: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-05-15 23:27:00.830 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-15 23:27:00.830 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-05-15 23:27:00.838 17953-17976/com.example.simpledice D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-05-15 23:27:00.840 17953-17976/com.example.simpledice D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-05-15 23:27:00.841 17953-17976/com.example.simpledice D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-05-15 23:27:00.917 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice W/mple.simpledic: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-05-15 23:27:00.917 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice W/mple.simpledic: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-05-15 23:27:01.018 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2392f10, tid 17974
2020-05-15 23:27:01.020 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-05-15 23:27:01.022 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-05-15 23:27:01.058 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf21b2970: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-05-15 23:27:01.090 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf21b2970: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf24f8810)
2020-05-15 23:27:01.117 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2020-05-15 23:27:01.118 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-05-15 23:27:01.118 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2392790, tid 17974
2020-05-15 23:27:01.119 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2020-05-15 23:27:01.136 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f9e13000 size 0x2000
2020-05-15 23:27:01.161 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-05-15 23:27:01.175 17953-17974/com.example.simpledice D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf21b2970: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf24f8810)
2020-05-15 23:27:07.408 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-15 23:27:07.409 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.simpledice, PID: 17953
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.simpledice.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:166)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
2020-05-15 23:27:07.430 17953-17953/com.example.simpledice I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17953 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't use" those things? Does a witch swoop down on her broom and hit your hands when you try to type? Do you get some sort of exception when you try to cast from String to int? Be more descriptive so we can help you solve the real problem, not the one you think you have.

Comment: First, does “crashes” mean it throws an exception ?  If so, what one?   Second, are you SURE resultHist1 is not null ?  Third, what happens if you try `int I = Integer.parseInt(“123”);`

Comment: @MarsAtomic Please see my update

Comment: `val i = textView.text.toString().toInt()`

Comment: @racraman "result" populates with a random integer using Random.nextInt(4).  "resultHist1" populates with the integer in "result" right before "result" gets a new integer. After "resultHist1" copies "result", and "result" gets a new integer, that's where I'm putting in the code to sum the two textViews.  I don't see how it could be null.  I've run the app dozens of times and it works (up until trying to add this calculation).  Also, when I try to enter "int" it just goes red; it doesn't populate as an option in the drop-down.  I get "Unresolved reference: int"

Comment: In Android Studio, click the Help menu and select the About menu item. What version of Android Studio does it say you're on? I'm thinking you might have a compatibility problem which is forcing you to use a workaround. ([X Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: @MarsAtomic

Android Studio 4.0 RC 1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6453388, built on May 1, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 12
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:

Comment: Please click on the File menu and select Project Structures. In the dialog that comes up, click SDK on the left. Towards the bottom of the dialog, you should see a combobox for JDK. What version of JDK is targetted?

Comment: @MarsAtomic File > Project Structure... > The only option I see on the left is "SDK Location", and from there I don't see any information about my JDK version.  Just "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\jre".  I did open that file myself, however, and the release notepad says:
JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_242"
OS_NAME="Windows"
OS_VERSION="5.2"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
SOURCE=""
(Hope that helps)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by JDK target. It seems your setup is in order. I know that if you use a version of JDK unsupported by Kotlin, you can get the "Unresolved reference" message on standard Java classes, but something else is going on here, and seeing as I don't actually use Android Studio, I'm sadly out of my depth. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get text from textview like this

```
 val a = result.text.toString()
 val b = resultHist1.text.toString()

 if(!a.isNullOrEmpty() &&  !b.isNullOrEmpty() ){
    val a = a.toInt()
    val b = b.toInt()
    calcHist1.text = (a+b).toString()
   }
   else
   {
   calcHist1.text = ""
   }
```

Comment: I tried this but my AVD app still crashes, and I'm not seeing any errors explaining why. As soon as I click the button that runs this code, the app crashes.  (just the app, not the AVD emulator)  Also, to execute those two lines, I'm using calcHist1.text = (a+b).toString()

Comment: can you post your logcat?